# Authorization in Google Calendar v3 by login and password

Tags: .net, calendar, passwords, authorization

Is there some way to a generated oAuth Client Secret and Client ID from my application, by writing username and password? I mean, my problem looks that:
I must write application for a absolutely dilettante people, and this would be a little unfit if they would must go to the "some site", generated their own Client ID and Client Secret, and REMEMBER this (saved somewhere or something). The greatest way, would be if he could give his gmail account and password and client id and client secret would generate automatically. 
I mean, i hear in a some applications being connected with Google Calendar, there's they has to only give their password and name of google acount, and this just is connecting with Google Calendar. Please, try to understand me- this must be application for ORDINARY people, not a programmer. How is it that in the many of applications which are connected with some Google API, there's user doesn't has to generate client Id and client secret on the site google developer console, and other "strange"
things for ordinary persons, They just write their google account, password, and that's all.

Comment: Perhaps with a handy library? https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-net/

Comment: I am not asking about ASP .NET application, I am creating desktop application, which is connecting with Google Calendar API v3. I see this is

Comment: Client my application can't open web browser to a login, he must writing user and password in application. And second thing: I can't see any information, that login thanks this library is automatically downloading client ID and client secret... Google is unbelievable stupid, they think that ordinary people will be go on a google developer console, and download client id and client secret and saving these looong texts to a login omfg... In a v2 that was much smarter